# How to reload child component when select value of parent component changes

Tags: angular

I have a select in the navbar of my app component. I need to refresh my child component when select value changes. Where do I need to make the refresh ?

This is the function that get the value from the select, in my parent component :

```
public setSelection(selectedValue: any): void {
    this.service = selectedValue;
    this.data.currentService.subscribe(service => this.service = service)
  }
```

This is my service where I pass the datas :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class DataService{

  private serviceSource = new BehaviorSubject(3);
  currentService = this.serviceSource.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  changeService(service: number){
    this.serviceSource.next(service);
  }

}
```

And this is how I get the value in my child component :

```
@Input() public service !: number;


ngOnInit() : void {

this.data.currentService.subscribe(service => this.service = service);

}
```

I just want the child component to be refresh when I change the selected option in my select in the parent component

Comment: you can use `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void { }` for detecting the parent component input value. 
https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: Yes I know, but when I do : ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.service = changes.service.currentValue
    console.log(this.service);
  }

I have nothing that is logged.

Comment: try to change ```@Input() public service !: number;``` to ```service: number;``` assuming that `this.data` is an instance of your `DataService`.

Comment: yes, this.data is an instance of DataService, but it doesn't work. There is nothing logged in the console.

Comment: is it possible the console.log is running before the value has changed? The suggestions here seem correct, but from the code line you wrote it seems that the console call may be running at the same time you are trying to get a response from the service, but its hard to tell not in a code block.